# use-ajax Class does not work if used in multiple views?

Tags: views, 8, ajax

What seems like a pretty straight forward implementation of ajaxifying a link is not working if I use it in more than one view block on the page.

I have a route that calls a function. In my view I have simple links that hit that route such as:

```
<a href="/delete/paragraph/81" class="use-ajax">Delete</a>
```

Here is the **Controller**

```
  public function DeleteEntityParagraph($pid) {
    $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AlertCommand('wtf'));
    // $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'refreshView', []));

    return $response;
  }
```

It all works fine. You click it, it throbs and returns the alert response. But then if I make another view block, with different content, and put it on the same page, the links on the second view do not use the ajax behavior.

The first views links will continue to work with the ajax behavior. If I remove the first view, the second views links will begin to work. Whichever view block occurs first is the only one with working ajax links.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Ive searched high and low. [Found this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/769258) but I don't think it is related

Comment: I am not having such issues on separate views on same page, at least not with ajax modal. IE: `<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/1">Node 1</a>`. Any errors in the browser console? Are you able to reproduce the issue on a fresh Drupal Install?

Comment: Oops yes there was an unrelated error happening from another script which was affecting this. derp! Thanks!